# File System with permission as "rwxrwSrwx"

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I have a shared directory from SAN, whenever I create a folder or file inside that directory, it already has permissions; for directory we have "drwxrwxrwx" permission and for files we have "rwxrwSrwx"
Now I am having trouble reading these files from my application and want to change their permission but they won't change. I used 755, -R 755, a-s, g-s to no effect.

Appreciate your help

Regards,
Ali

Comment: Can you give the output of  `ls -l` for the file?

Answer (score 1):

You have misidentified the problem. `man ls` says:

```
S If in <owner permissions>, the file is not executable and set- user-ID mode is set. If in <group permissions>, the file is not executable and set-group-ID mode is set.
```

So, `rwxrwSrwx` includes `rwxrw-rwx`.

Do `mount`, check the options and `man 8 mount`.

Also, check the permissions of the parent directories:

```
ls -ld . .. ../.. ../../..
```

Recheck your code for bugs.

Check the logs on the server.

Check your `umask` locally and on the server.

.

Comment: I think you are right, because I can touch a file in directory, I can even delete files. But I have an application (installed on linux) which needs to open these files for reading and that application cannot read these files from this directory, I copied some files to another directory and my application can read it just fine. I check my mount and these files are mounted with CIFS protocol, could this be a problem? following is the whole syntax we used in fstab: 
"<directory> <directory> cifs userame=abc,password=abc,sec=ntlmssp,uid=8005,gid=805,domain=abc.com.pk

Comment: and the user with uid=8005 is the owner of the application i want to run

Answer (score 0):

The `S` in the group permission bit means that [setuid](https://danielmiessler.com/study/unixlinux_permissions/) bit is turned on the file.

Basically you can remove it with `chmod g-s filename`

It might be you need to launch with [sudo](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm) command:

`sudo chmod g-s filename`

**[Proof of concept]**

> -rwxrwSrwx. 1 apache k.sewnundun      24 Dec  4 10:30 a.sh

`sudo chmod g-s a.sh`

> -rwxrw-rwx. 1 apache k.sewnundun 24 Dec  4 10:30 a.sh

Comment: I tried, my nomral user is not in sudo group so i tried with root and still not change :-(